# Java: Passing variables to different classes

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and wrote a program using code like  `this.room1 = new room1` to help pass my variables to different classes using the global variable...I was wondering if there us a way to do it without using `this.`? My code works exactly the way its supposed to. It asks the user for the length and width of 2 rooms, calculates the area, then it assigns the smaller room to the children and the larger room to the adults....This is my code:

```
    public rooms(double L, double W) {
        this.L = L;
        this.W = W;
    }
    //method to calculate area
    public double area() {
        return L*W;
    }
    //get and set methods
    public double getL() {
        return L;
    }
    public void setL(double L) {
        this.L = L;
    }
    public double getW() {
        return W;
    }
    public void setW(double W) {
        this.W = W;
    }
}
```

Comment: the short answer is no because you pass an argument name to a function the same as one of your member variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use the word "this" here. room1 is accessible to all non-static methods within that class (assuming you did not declare room1 again in another non-static method). However, using "this" is helpful for those reading your code. It will tell the reader that the variable was already declared earlier in your program and assist with debugging later on.

Comment: Thank you for your help...I figured it out and I feel quite dumb..lol...I just created new variable names instead of using this. and using the same variable name...

Comment: @pikprogram can you please mark this as solved :). Thanks!  Preferably mine if you found it helpful :).

Answer (score 0):

those are not global variables, but members of your class (object)

```
public house() {
    // these 2 lines are equivalent:
    this.room1 = new rooms();
    room1 = new rooms();
}

public house(rooms room1, rooms room2) {
    // here you need the this, otherwise the compiler assumes you
    // mean room1 that you got as a parameter to your function
    this.room1 = room1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there *i*s a way to do it without using `this.`?

## No.

If the names of the **instance** variables are the same as those of the **static** variables, then you can't do it.

---

Suppose their names were not the same, like in this:

```
public house(rooms r1, rooms r2) {
    this.room1 = r1;
    this.room2 = r2;
}
```

Then it could have been written like this:

```
public house(rooms r1, rooms r2) {
    room1 = r1;
    room2 = r2;
}
```